# Azure VM - Start / Power-On with RDP or PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Kid went off to college - wants to use his Surface RT to access a VM I created for him on Azure.

Anyone have a way to power the VM on & off without giving him the keys to my Azure account?

If there isn't a way to do it in PS or RDP is there script I could put on a .NET site that he could http to to start and stop the VM?

Comment: If someone can run a PowerShell script to start and stop an Azure VM, that means they have credentials to do so. You'd either have to write an app to do it, as you suggested, or deploy a vm to a resource group that you give them limited rights to, so they could start/stop on their own. In any case: this question is better suited to ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Sorry for the lag getting back, had a roll-out that skipped 3 major upgrades that TPTB gave an inadequate test period to which created massive work on my end - David, thank you - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create or Add user account for him, then give the user VM contributor role. When he logs in to the portal with his credentials he should only have access to stop and start VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#virtual-machine-contributor

Comment: Sorry for the lag getting back, had a roll-out that skipped 3 major upgrades that TPTB gave an inadequate test period to which created massive work on my end - Hannel, thank you - very helpful- I added him first as a VM user than read your fine note and Jason Ye's fine note and realized it was VM Contributer - couldn't ahve done it without you two, thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Hannel, you can create an Azure AD user for your kid, then grant he the resource permission, he can logs in Azure portal to start or stop that VM.

You can create Azure AD account follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/add-users-azure-active-directory).

Then you can grant permission to that account, like this:[image]

You can give he the **owner** role to he, also you can select **Virtual Machine Contribute** (`Can manage virtual machines, but not the virtual network or storage account to which they are connected`)to he, more information about Azure built-in roles, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#virtual-machine-contributor).

Also you can define a new role to he, about Custom roles please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry for the lag getting back, had a roll-out that skipped 3 major upgrades that TPTB gave an inadequate test period to which created massive work on my end - Jason Ye, thank you - very helpful - the screen shot really helped me get to the right blade.

Comment: I did accept - I'm too new for it to register the click.  Thank you again.